# Is there any downside in indicating a wifi network as "unmetered"? (assume the wifi has no bandwidth restrictions or max data limit)

Tags: wi-fi, android-11

I use a wifi network that has no bandwidth restrictions or max data limit with I use the latest Venmo app on Android 10 with Samsung Galaxy S9. Android detected the wifi network as metered. Is there any downside if I indicate this wifi network as "unmetered" instead?

---

Android [detected](https://www.lorier.net/docs/android-metered.html) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20210926010222/https://www.lorier.net/docs/android-metered.html)) the wifi network as metered:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't any downside and you should set it to unmetered. You certainly wouldn't like OTA updates or large downloads to be throttled or stopped by setting it as metered.

[When to use **metered** Wi-Fi](https://support.google.com/android/answer/9654714?hl=en#zippy=%2Ccontrol-data-use-with-metered-wi-fi)

> If your network has a data limit, you can set your Wi-Fi as metered. When your network is metered, you have more control over how much data your phone uses through downloads and other apps.